# How to set command line permissions after npm install

Tags: terminal, command-line, permission, verify

I am trying to run the `gatsby-cli` on a fresh install of macOS.

I downloaded `npm` and `node` from https:node.js.org/en.

Then installed the packages.

Then installed `npm i -g gatsby-cl`.

However, when I try to run a command like `gatsby build` I get a string of errors like

```
"libpangoft2-1.0.0.dylib" cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.
```

I got into `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Allow Anyway` but the execution sequence stops and the `Allow` command is not saved.

How to I grant permissions to these executables so I can run `gatsby` commands without the popups?

Comment: Have you tried ```sudo gatsby build```? Also, you can try getting Node and NPM from HomeBrew although I'm not sure that it would make much of a difference.

Comment: `sudo gatsby build` throws the same error. I was hesitant to install via Homebrew because I don't know how to uninstall the current version of `node/npm`.

Comment: You can search your computer for uninstaller or see if Homebrew overwrites the current Installation. I have no problems with my installation of NPM using Homebrew. What version of macOS are you using?

Comment: I found a tutorial on Stack Exchange for a manual uninstall, not sure if I got it all. I reinstalled with Homebrew and am getting the same error sequence.

Comment: It seems to be more related to running the `cli` than node itself.

Answer (score 1):

Adding Terminal permissions in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy corrects this issue.

[image]